# Image Isnt Showing Despite It Being In The Html

Tags: html, css, blogger

The issue I'm having is with an image that I would like to have appear alongside the search bar default wording "search". Even though I have coded in the URL for the image I would like to appear, the image doesn't appear.  I have installed a custom search bar by following the instructions in this tutorial - http://www.bloominrouge.com/2015/01/a-simple-and-sleek-search-bar-widget.html.

Below I have included the entire coding for the search bar:

```css
     #search {
       text-align: left;
       margin-right: -5.5%;
       width: 100%;
       float: right;
       max-width: 210px;
       border: 0;
     }
     #searchform {
       height: 20px;
     }
     #search #s {
       background: #f8f8f8 url(http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/829C0943-C2A2-4052-BFF5-49E6606F44B6_zps3r9lpyvb.gif)98% 50% no-repeat;
       color: #333333;
       font-size: 10.5px!important;
       font-family: karla, arial;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       text-decoration: none;
       font-weight: normal;
       letter-spacing: 0.09em;
       border: 0;
       width: 60%;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
       outline: none;
       position: relative;
       top: 11px;
       padding-left: 6px;
     }
```

```html
<div id='search' title='Type and hit enter'>
  <form action='/search' id='searchform' method='get'>
    <input id='s' name='q' onblur='if (this.value == &quot;&quot;)   {this.value = &quot;Search&quot;;}' onfocus='if (this.value == &quot;Search&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;;}' type='text' value='Search' />
  </form>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: Please consider the use of input placeholders.

Comment: I dont see no <img> tag

Comment: @ewrwr — It's a background image.

Comment: just do *{background-img:url('urlname');}  To the whole page, isnt that what you want?

Comment: The value attribute is not a substitute for a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), trying to use it as one has serious accessibility implications.

Comment: As stated by @Quentin probably you have to adjust the size of the image, try using other source, like [this image](http://i.imgur.com/b04e5nq.gif?1)

Answer (score 1):

The image is showing up.

It's just that the image is large and mostly transparent so the entire area that actually appears inside the input doesn't contain any coloured pixels.

Possibly you are looking for `background-size: contain` (or an image that starts out at a sensible size!).